# Build Assimp with Cygwin

Tags: build, compilation, cygwin, assimp

i want to build Assimp using cmake with cygwin.

According to cmake documentation,cmake has 7 Makefile generators:

```
Borland Makefiles
MSYS Makefiles
MinGW Makefiles
NMake Makefiles
NMake Makefiles JOM
Unix Makefiles
Watcom WMake
```

But there isn't any Makefile generator for cygwin.

How can i build Assimp with cygwin?

Comment: cygwin has its own cmake package. Have you tried it ?

Comment: yes,i tried cygwin cmake

Comment: and the result is ?

Answer (score 0):

building on cygwin, there is an issue on `strcasecmp`

```
/pub/tmp/assimp-5.0.1/include/assimp/StringComparison.h:146:14: error: ‘::strcasecmp’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘strncmp’?
  146 |     return ::strcasecmp(s1,s2);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
      |              strncmp
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html
It is due to Cygwin still considering it as an extention

A second problem arise from convoluted C++ templates

```
[ 37%] Building CXX object code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/IFC/IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/as: CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/IFC/IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.o: too many sections (88485)
/tmp/cc95KPdy.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc95KPdy.s: Fatal error: can't write 180 bytes to section .text of CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/IFC/IFCReaderGen1_2x3.cpp.o: 'file too big'
```

and we can take the solution from:
https://digitalkarabela.com/mingw-w64-how-to-fix-file-too-big-too-many-sections/

A third problem is

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/as: CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/StepFile/StepFileGen1.cpp.o: section .xdata$_ZNSt11_Tuple_implILm1EJSt14default_deleteIN6Assimp8StepFile31draughting_callout_relationshipEEEE7_M_headERS5_: string table overflow at offset 10000005
/tmp/ccNl78l4.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccNl78l4.s: Fatal error: can't close CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/Importer/StepFile/StepFileGen1.cpp.o: file too big
```

and the suggestion to use -O1 from
[gcc string table overflow error during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125007/gcc-string-table-overflow-error-during-compilation)

works.
With all of them we can:

```
tar -xf assimp-5.0.1.tar.gz
cd assimp-5.0.1
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-D_GNU_SOURCE -Wa,-mbig-obj -O1" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-D_GNU_SOURCE -Wa,-mbig-obj -O1" .
make
```

and finally

```
....
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/unit.exe
[100%] Built target unit
```

Comment: I successfully compiled Assimp with  cygwin,thank you.

Comment: I don ' t understand you?

Comment: @user3552351 Press the green checkmark to the left of the answer to mark your question as solved.